# Approximation of an option price

Tags: option-pricing, volatility, greeks, delta, gamma

The value of an option in the money is 11.50 Euros. The parameters of the market are: 
-The price of the underlying stock: 81.4 Euros.

-The volatility ofthe underlying is : 34.65 %

The sensitivities are:

Delta = 58%

Gamma = 2

I would like to approximate the price of this option if the price of the underlying increase by 1/2 Euros (volatility not changed)

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the volatility is not changing, we can assume that the only change is the underlying asset price $S$. Then
\begin{align*}
C(S+\Delta) &\approx C(S) + Delta \times\Delta +\frac{1}{2} Gamma \times \Delta^2 \\
&=11.50 + 0.58 \times 0.5 + \frac{1}{2}\times 2 \times (0.5)^2\\
&=12.04.
\end{align*}